# Timeshift, use a regular directory instead of remounting the partition under /run/timeshift

Tags: timeshift

Is it possible to have timeshift just create snapshots in a given directory, instead of remounting the whole partition somewhere in /run/timeshift ?

There are files on that partition that I need to access with no change whatsoever.